# Iterate through array of variables passing each one to a function in PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, function, powershell, foreach

I have a function that exports the results of a SQL query to a json file:

```
# Connect to SQL Server
$SqlCommand.CommandText = $Query;
$SqlCommand.Connection = $SqlConnection;

# Execute query and get the result back
$QueryResult = $SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()

# Hold query result in data table
$QueryTable = New-Object "System.Data.DataTable"
$QueryTable.Load($QueryResult)

# Export query results to json
$QueryTable | Select-Object $QueryTable.Columns.ColumnName | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "$OutputDirectory\$SqlInstance-$QueryName.json"
```

And I have multiple queries that I want to execute and have created variables for each one:

```
$q1 = "SELECT blah"
$q2 = "SELECT more blah"
$q3 = "SELECT even more blah"
```

I call the function by:

```
ExportQueryResultsToJson -Query $q1 -QueryName "q1"
```

I have around 80 queries that I want to execute so instead of having 80 lines of `ExportQueryResultsToJson ...` I want to use `ForEach`. I've created an array of variables:

```
$SqlServer2012QueryArray = @(
    $q1,
    $q2,
    $q3
)
```

I've tried many variations of the following:

```
foreach ($Query in $SqlServer2012QueryArray) {
    $Expression = "ExportQueryResultsToJson -Query '$Query' -QueryName $Query"
    Invoke-Expression $Expresion
}
```

And I've tried using a splat but I can't figure out how to pass all queries in correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach this in a number of ways. Three possible ways, which are all very algorithmically similar, are below:

---

**Using Your Array:**

The solution depends on your array `$sqlserver2012QueryArray` having a list of sequentially numbered variables in the format `q<number>`. The first variable name must be `q1`.

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $sqlserver2012QueryArray.Count; $i++) {
    ExportQueryResultsToJson -Query $sqlserver2012QueryArray[$i] -QueryName $((Get-Variable "q$($i+1)").Name)
}
```

---

**Querying Already Created Variables:**

This solution relies on your variables being named in the format `q<number>`. They do not have to be sequentially named. It could capture unwanted variables if they are named like `q<number>abc`.

```
foreach ($var in (Get-Variable -Name q[0-9]*)) {
    ExportQueryResultsToJson -Query $var.Value -QueryName $var.Name
}
```

---

**Using a Hash Table:**

You can create a hash table with each key name being your variable name and the associated value being the query string. You can bypass creating the query variables all together with this solution by just inputting the query strings as the values.

```
$queryhash = @{'q1' = $q1; 'q2' = $q2; 'q3' = $q3; 'q14' = $q14}
foreach ($var in $queryhash.GetEnumerator()) {
    ExportQueryResultsToJson -Query $var.Value -QueryName $var.Key
}
```

---

**Note:** In all cases, you should try to avoid `Invoke-Expression`. It is not generally a safe command to use because it welcomes code injection. I also don't see why it is necessary at all in this case either.

Comment: You're awesome thank you. I went with the hash table option.